# Serve react project on dev througth proxy

Tags: reactjs, proxy, local-storage, create-react-app

I've split my react application in 3 different projects, using CRA for all of them, auth, X and Y. User is first sent to auth, then I redirect him to either X or Y based on some info.

It works perfectly on PRODUCTION environment (because they run on the same domain), but on dev, X and Y failed to authenticate the user, because they run on different ports (different domains) the data in local storage is not shared between auth, X and Y.

I've tried to find a way to use a reverse proxy (http-proxy)  to host the React dev servers on the same domain, but failed too, because the services could not find the assets/static folder, resulting in 404. Also tried http-proxy-middleware, as it is recommended on the CRA docs page, but failed to do so. Is there an easier way that I'm not seeing?

Edit: Found something new, but also failed. Used react-rewired to override CRA scripts, to use PUBLIC_PATH on DEV, but now my bundle.js returns an index.html file.

The following code does redirect to the accordingly react project, but the assets are requested to the wrong path.

```
const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();


app.all("/login/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Login');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: servers.login});
});

app.all("/implementacao/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Implementation');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: servers.implementation});
});
```

So I used react-rewired to change the public path

```
const {
  override,
} = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(
      (config) => {
        config.output.publicPath = '/login/';
        return config;
      },
  ),

  jest: config => {
    return config;
  },

  devServer: configFunction => (proxy, allowedHost) => {
    return configFunction(proxy, allowedHost);
  },

  paths: (paths, env) => {
    return paths;
  }
};
```

Now, the assets requests are made correctly to /login/, but nothing the dev server always return an index.html file.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understood your question but something similar happened to me. I had to set the `homepage` in `package.json` as well as update the `Router`
`<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>`

Comment: I found the issue, will post the solution here when I have time, but it involves two PRs on CRA and one on Webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with react-app-rewired, to override config, and use publicPath on dev, the assets will not be served from the publicPath.

There is already a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/7259) on CRA to use PUBLIC_URL in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easier way that I'm not seeing?

Another approach would be to use multiple React Single Page Applications (SPAs) inside one application, see [crisp-react](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react). E.g. instead of 3 CRAs in 3 applications/projects have 3 SPAs in one application/project. The backend surely can get data from other backend servers transparently for each SPA.

Comment: Looks cool, but how do I migrate from a set of existing CRA projects to using crisp-react ?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I migrate from a set of existing CRA projects to using crisp-react ?

**Background**
crisp-react comes with two stock SPAs called ‘First’ and ‘Second’. Both render some explanatory/sample UI.

**Migration overview**
1.Pick one CRA project and migrate it to the ‘First’ SPA. When finished, you have two CRAs left and two crisp-react SPAs: ‘First’ (renders your UI) and ‘Second’ (still renders the sample UI). Rename the ‘First’ SPA to give it more meaningful name.
2. Pick another CRA and migrate it. When finished, you have one CRA left and two crisp-react SPAs both rendering your UI.
3.Modify  crisp-react to add the third SPA and then migrate the remaining CRA to the third SPA.

**Migration steps (sketch)**
1.1 Follow crisp-react Getting Started.
1.2 The landing page of the First SPA is rendered by `crisp-react/client/src/entrypoints/first.tsx`
The landing page of the CRA is rendered by `src/index.tsx`
Replace the content of the former with the latter.
1.3 The first CRA consists of React components: `src/App.tsx` and others you added. Copy the components to `crisp-react/client/src/components/from-first-cra/`
1.4 Ensure crisp-react client app compiles: From `crisp-react/client/` execute: `yarn compile`
1.5 Ensure crisp-react client app builds: From `crisp-react/client/` execute: `yarn build`
1.6 Ensure crisp-react client looks ok without backend data: see client Usage Scenarios.
1.7 Get the backend (e.g. Express) involved: see backend Usage Scenarios.
1.8 Milestone reached: browser can be pointed to backend (Express) and get from it html files and bundles - which results in the first SPA rendering initial UI (to the extent  possible without data supplied via API enpoints).
1.9 Decide how the the first SPA will get data from API. 3 basic choices here:
 - the API endpoints are implemented in Express so you can retire your backend servers
 - Express does expose API endpoints but acts as a reverse proxy getting data from your backend servers
 - Express knows nothing about API and data supplied by backend servers that are queried directly by the components inside the first SPA.
2.1 Second SRA
as above
...

Comment: Looks cool, will give it a try if we have extra time at the end of the sprint. Thank you for the effort. And you might want to group your answers.